# Change language of chrome translation

Tags: chrome-for-android, languages, google-translate

I have Marshmallow and the latest Chrome. My phone language is set to Italian.

When I open in chrome sites in foreign languages it proposes to translate it in Italian.

For Japanese pages I noticed using Google translate that English translation is much more accurate than Italian.

Therefore I would like to know if it is possible to force Chrome on Android to translate Japanese into English instead of Italian.

Setting the browser in English would be a good workaround but I found how to do so just in the Windows version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. 
In Android Chrome go to [chrome://translate-internals](http://chrome://translate-internals)

Change the only editable parameter from your language code to 
en

Now restart Chrome.

When you open a page in a language different from yours and English you see the usual "do you want to translate..." question but source and target language are now clickable and you can change them as needed.